# When sending emails from/as someone else, do Google Apps Script quotas go against the user executing or the from/as user?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, quota

I have my Gmail account configured to let me send emails as another Gmail account.

When I send emails from a GAS project on my account, but sending from/as the other account, whose quotas are used?

If I (`me@example.com`) run the following script, will it use my (`me@example.com`) quota or the quota of `anotherUser@example.com`?

```
function myFunction() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail("example@example.com", "test me", "test me", {
    "from": "anotherUser@example.com"
  });
}
```

Comment: I believe it's `me@example.com`